# Can a weak Muslim country at war with a powerful Muslim country seek help from a powerful non-Muslim country?

Tags: halal-haram, non-muslim-countries, war

Suppose two Muslim countries are at war, one weak country and one powerful country, and the weak one expects to be conquered.

**Question**: Can a weak Muslim country at war with a powerful Muslim country seek help from a powerful non-Muslim country?

I'm aware of [Qur'an 60:1](https://quran.com/60/1) which says:

> O you who have believed, do not take My enemies and your enemies as allies, extending to them affection while they have disbelieved in what came to you of the truth, having driven out the Prophet and yourselves [only] because you believe in Allah, your Lord. If you have come out for jihad in My cause and seeking means to My approval, [take them not as friends]. You confide to them affection, but I am most knowing of what you have concealed and what you have declared. And whoever does it among you has certainly strayed from the soundness of the way.

This prohibits taking non-Muslim allies under certain circumstances, but I'm unclear if this is applicable in the above scenario, where the alternative to taking non-Muslim allies is to allow one's country to be conquered.

Comment: I've heavily edited to reflect how I would phrase things: (a) I replaced the "wall of text" with formatted text, (b) I've highlighted the exact question, making it unambiguous and easy to find, (c) I've added a quote from the Qur'an in order to show research effort, (d) I got rid of the repetition and unnecessary parts, and (e) checked the grammar, spelling, and punctuation [there may still be blips, but some effort shows].  Hopefully this gives the idea of how questions can be improved.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones Can I ask you one thing?